# Change background of div which is wrapped in anchor on a:hover?

Tags: css

I would like to change the background image of div.button on `#pianist a:hover`. Is this possible with CSS?

```
<a id="pianist">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <h2>PIANIST</h2>
</a>
```

Comment: Is the anchor the same size as the button?

Comment: The anchor is a little bit larger, and also contains the text "PIANIST" which appears below the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it by nesting it under `#pianist:hover` like so:

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/QNkh6/)

```
#pianist:hover .button {
    background-color: red; /* replace with desired background declaration */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.. just use: `#pianist:hover .button`

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vH6LU/)

```
.button {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
}
#pianist:hover .button {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');
}
```